Make a non-smooth function smooth
I am dealing with a piecewise affine function $f$ defined as follows: $f(x)=0$ if $x<1$, $f(x)=1-x$ if $x\in [1,2]$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise.

I want to make it smooth. I looked at sigmoid functions of the form:
$$
g_{a,b}(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-a(x-b)}},
$$
but I think that these functions are useful only when dealing with indicator functions. I thought of adding a circle arc to make smooth the corners:

But I am stuck on how to parametrize them so I get a smooth function $g_{\epsilon}$ that converges to $f$ when $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

Would this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1508257/1104384

@BrunoB thanks for the answer, but I could not find a "smooth partition of unity": function that is equal to 1 over [-a/2,a/2] and 0 over [-a,a] and smooth in between

Try looking up the keyword "mollifier", you will find a function that satisfies these prerequisites on the Wikipedia page for example.

If the curvature starts at $x=1$ it would not be possible to match the slope of $1-x$, so the smooth approximation should start a bit earlier.
If with smooth you mean a function class $C^\infty$, modifying what is said here I did the following approximation:
$$s(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\ x\leq \frac58;\\ 
-1,\ x\geq \frac{19}{8};\\ 
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{56\sqrt{3}(3-2x)}{(8x-19)(8x-5)}\right)}-1,\ \frac58<x<\frac{19}{8};\end{cases}$$
which correspond to the function from the source translated and scaled by $\hat{x}\equiv \frac{x-5/8}{7/4}$.
I found it visually by trial and error so surely it could be improved.
You can check its plot in Desmos.

